# What could you say about such DB working?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, design-patterns, refactoring

I'm reviewing some code of guy who have in his WCF Service:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IDBService
{
    [OperationContract]
    void DBUpdateInsert(string sql, params string[] parameters);

    [OperationContract]
    object DBSelect(string sql, params string[] parameters);
}
```

And every function that needs invokes of SQL code uses this service.

What pros and cons of such way? It seems so uncertain for me.

Comment: Wide open to injection attacks of any kind.

Comment: @Corak you wouldn't need to "inject" - it is just wide open to attack

Answer (score 8):

Shudder. That isn't an API - it is is a hole. Part of the point of SOA is to isolate different pieces - allowing minor changes to your DB to not impact service callers. Here, the caller supplies raw SQL. That means they need incestuous knowledge of the DB. So it violates encapsulation. However, there are other serious issues:

Most important:

- once you have a service, you **do not trust the caller**. That could be your application, but it could be that someone just looked at the app, saw what it connected to, and is using your service from *their own code*. You cannot trust **anything** that comes into a service application. Certainly not SQL. The same as how you (presumably) wouldn't put raw SQL as a hidden input on an HTML page that you then execute in a web application: again, because you *do not trust the caller*.

Also:

- security: what can/can't the caller access? can they issue `"delete from Orders"` ? you have *no* ability to sanitize what the caller can / cannot do
- `string[]` parameters - not all values are unambiguous as strings; this demonstrates no understanding of the data model - just "stuff"
- returning `object` - well, that isn't a data-contract *anyway*, so won't work under most WCF bindings - although `NetDataContractSerializer` might forgive you if it is feeling generous

But, again, this is **not** an API. An API would expose discreet data under well known, controlled services, with typed parameters. There are a dozen and twenty ways of setting up a decent API - from individual methods (at the "controlled" end) through to things like OData (at the "open" end) - but *none* of those will be passing SQL around.

If I had to guess: this developer was writing a rich client application with direct SQL access, and was told to expose the data through a service. Rather than actually *write* a service, they have simply exposed their existing SQL code at the WCF layer. That is backwards. Their existing SQL code (the discreet SQL operations, like `GetCustomer` etc) should have **become** the WCF layer. The calling client should forget all about any SQL it knows, and bind to the WCF service instead.